# hook_menu() item is not showing in primary-links even it exist in menu_links and menu_router tables

Tags: routes, hooks

I'm using `hook_menu()` in my module which defines a menu item in the primary-links.

I flushed the cache and refreshed the modules page but the item didn't show in the primary-links.
I checked the menu_links and menu_router tables and the item was defined it them.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['newuser'] = array(
    'title' => 'Register',
    'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
    'page callback' => 'register_browse_page',
    'access callback' => 'newuser_access_callback',
  );

  return $items;
}

function newuser_access_callback() {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid == 0 && user_access('access content')) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

function register_browse_page() {
  $form = drupal_get_form("newuser_form");
  return theme("newuser_form_page", $form);
}
```

What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: It's likely to be the `access callback`...try unconditionally returning `TRUE` as a test. If the menu item appears you know that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition in your `newuser_access_callback` tells to your link to shows only to anonymous.

```
if ($user->uid == 0 && user_access('access content')) {
```

If you want see it as admin also, you should add yourself like that

```
if ($user->uid == 1 || ($user->uid == 0 && user_access('access content'))) {
```

Comment: ok i tested this code and it worked correctly i thought that the link should appear in the primary links admin page despite the permissions but that was wrong thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu to be visible to anonymous users, you should use the following code.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['newuser'] = array(
    'title' => 'Register',
    'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
    'page callback' => 'register_browse_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

This is similar to the code used in [openid_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!openid!openid.module/function/openid_menu/6).

```
function openid_menu() {
  $items['openid/authenticate'] = array(
    'title' => 'OpenID Login', 
    'page callback' => 'openid_authentication_page', 
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous', 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
    'file' => 'openid.pages.inc',
  );

  //...
}
```

[user_is_anonymous()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/6) also allows administrators to see items for anonymous when administering, as long as the global $menu_admin is set to `TRUE`. This is done before checking which users have access to a menu handler.

```
function user_is_anonymous() {
  // Menu administrators can see items for anonymous when administering.
  return !$GLOBALS['user']->uid || !empty($GLOBALS['menu_admin']);
}
```

Normally, [user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/6) should instead be used as access callback.

Checking if the user anonymous user has the permission to access to the content is not necessary; plus, the code would work if you assign that permission to anonymous users.